# Combining php and html tags on the onclick event

Tags: javascript, php, html

I get this error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

with this code:

```
<script>
  function go(location) {
    alert(location);
    document.getElementById('main_frame').src = location;
  }
</script>
<header class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="navbar-header">
         <button class="navbar-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">Pier Capitan</a>
            <nav class="collapse navbar-collapse" role="navigation">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <?php foreach($links as $link){ ?>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#" onclick="go(<?php echo base_url().$link->link_address ?>)"><?php echo strtoupper($link->link_address) ?></a>
                        </li>
                    <?php } ?>
                </ul>
            </nav><!-- end of navbar collapse -->
    </div><!-- end of navbar header -->
</header>
<br><br><br><br><br><br>
<div class="col-md-12">
<iframe src="about:blank" id="main_frame" height="500" width="100%" frameborder="0"></iframe>
</div>
```

I just need to pass the link to the "go" script so I can change the source of the iframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="go('<?php echo base_url().$link->link_address ?>')"><?php echo strtoupper($link->link_address) ?></a>
```